# Added a total 12GB RAM to laptop, but only 3.2GB is usable

Tags: windows-8, memory, bios, upgrade

I have an HP Pavilion 15Z e000 x64 with Windows 8.

It shows that I'm using less ram after the upgrade than before. The BIOS is hardware reserving 9.8gbs

Comment: Most likely your motherboard does not fully support the new ram. Try upgrading your bios, or returning the ram. Also, I assume you are running a 64 bit version. (32bit maxes out at 3.2 gb usable)

Answer (score 11):

[From Crucial:](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Pavilion%2015z-e000%20Series&Cat=RAM)

**Your Pavilion 15z-e000 Series System Specs**

```
Memory Type: DDR3 PC3-12800, DDR3 PC3-14900, DDR3 (non-ECC)
Maximum Memory: 8GB 
Slots: 2
```

Generally, the maximum size for each slot is the maximum ram divided by the number of slots (in this case 4GB). Since you've purchased `12GB` of ram for `2` slots, I'm going to guess one of those is a `8GB` module. You can't use an `8GB` module in a slot that only supports up to `4GB`.

I was under the impression that most computers will just disregard the rest of the ram within the module, so that it's still compatible. But unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case with your computer. I would suggest returning the ram to the store you bought it at (ASAP) and purchasing a `4GB` module instead.

Next time you purchase ram, keep in mind that the memory you buy is determined by:

- **CPU:** not all `x64` CPUs support the same amount of ram, even though they mostly support `32GB`
- **Motherboard:** Even with `x64` CPUs, you may only be able to have, ie, `8GB` on your motherboard (this, more specifically, is a limitation of the memory manager and number of slots on your MOBO). Your motherboard also determines how fast the RAM can run (but this isn't suppose to affect compatibility).
- **OS:** there are `64b` and `32b` versions of almost every operating system, and it doesn't just mean `4GB` vs `inifnite GB`. Look up your OS and find out how much ram you can add (`32b` versions of Windows will actually be limited to `3.5GB` or `3GB`).

Comment: 32-bit versions of Windows are actually limited to 3.5GB, so when I first saw the title of this question that was the first thing I thought of.  The OP just said "Windows 8", not indicating bitness, so that could still be it... but I suspect that you're right about the 8GB module not being usable.

Comment: @MT_Head your right, I forgot about that. But I did look up the computer, and it does come with the `64b` version of Windows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right: the OP says "It shows that I'm using less ram after the upgrade than before", which says (to me) that the machine was reporting more than 3.2 GB before.  I seem to have muddied the waters with my comment; I just wanted to say that the *title* (if not the actual text) of the question makes this look like a bitness issue.  At first glance, anyway.

Comment: @MT_Head yeah it definitely does

Comment: `Generally, the maximum size for each slot is the maximum ram divided by the number of slots`   Generally (or not). The motherboard manual will (or should) say for sure.